# Integrate Unity to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, integrate

I really tried to find any tutorial or help but doesn't end well so.

My question is:

I have an Unity Project, but I want to integrate with Android Studio, my idea is to make a APP in Android Studio, then with a button I want to call the Scene from Unity and add a button in Unity to go back to Android Studio.

I read a lot of tutorials from 2014 to 2017 I think but none of those works, also I export Unity Project and then Import in Android Studio but same result.

- Android Studio 3.2
- Unity 2018.2.9f1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is to generate an .aar of the Unity project and use it as library in my main Android project.Also use android studio 2.3.3 version, for some reason Unity's export project isn't compatible with the newest android studio version.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think I'm done, it didn't work for me and I was thinking maybe there are other ways to do that, I just want to build a normal APP with transacction, grids, info and in some options calls to virtual reality that's why I tried to build this app on Android Studio and call the virtual reality in Unity